# « J'ai migré » ou « j'ai fait migrer un site » ?

Tags: verbes, constructions, constructions-causatives

Qu'est-ce qui est correct **J'ai migré** un site vers un autre ou **J'ai fait migrer** ?

Pourquoi cette question ? En français il y a des cas avec et sans *fait*:

- J'ai fait laver le linge
- J'ai sorti le chien

Comment: Les exemples parallèles sont plutôt *j'ai séché/frit/brûlé/bouilli* vs *j'ai fait sécher/frire/brûler/bouillir*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't mean the same thing.

> J'ai fait laver le linge

It means you didn't wash it, but you got someone to do it for you.

> J'ai lavé le linge

It means you washed it yourself.

So it really depends what you mean. If you are the team manager, you would say

> J'ai fait migrer un site

and if you're a developper, you would say

> J'ai migré un site

Comment: Une petite note, comme la personne a mentionné l'exemple avec le chien, c'est que _j'ai fait sortir le chien_ ne signifie pas, usuellement du moins, le faire faire se promener par quelqu'un d'autre mais surtout le laisser sortir (seul), par exemple en ouvrant la porte. Merci !

Comment: @Làchus'n'AI Exemple intéressant en effet, je vais essayer de mettre un complément à ce sujet. Merci

Answer (score -1):

Migrer est intransitif. Il s'emploie pour des populations ou des êtres vivants (humains ou animales).

**migrer un site est donc incorrect.**

**faire migrer un site peut être acceptable** (en supposant que le site migre de lui-même sous cet effet).

Il vaudrait mieux employer convertir (pour un changement technique), ou déplacer (s'il y a une sorte de transfert géographique ou de plate-forme), ou transférer ...

Comment: Il s'agit ici d'une utilisation transitive courante dans le jargon informatique qui est calquée sur l'anglais *to migrate a site/an application*, etc. et qui recouvre plusieurs significations dont celles suggérées ici. Par exemple un site web est relocalisé vers un nouvel hébergeur (déplacé) ou est modifié pour être adapté à une nouvelle version de logiciel (converti).